# Bash IF not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to have a function, called from `PS1` which outputs something in a different colour, depending on what that something is.

- In this case it's `$?`, the exit status of a program.
- **I am trying to get this function to output red text if the exit status is anything other than `0`.**
- I have tried all possible variations of this, ways of representing that variable in the conditions and so forth and it just isn't working.

Instead of outputting what I expect it's just either always `$LRED` in one variation of this `IF`, or always `$HII` in another variation of this `IF`.

All relevant `BASH` is posted below, can you guys offer any insight?

```
...

# Custom Colour Alias
NM="\[\033[0;38m\]" # No background and white lines
HI="\[\033[1;36m\]" # Username colour
HII="\[\033[0;37m\]" # Name colour
SI="\[\033[1;32m\]" # Directory colour
IN="\[\033[0m\]" # Command input color
LRED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
BRW="\[\033[0;33m\]"

...

exitStatus ()
{
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
            echo "$LRED\$?"
        else
            echo "\$?"
    fi
    #echo \$?
}

...

export PS1="\n$HII[ $LRED\u $SI\w$NM $HII]\n[ \! / \# / $(exitStatus) $HII]$LRED $ $IN"
```

### CODE BASED ON SOLUTION

This is what I did based on the **accepted answer** below.

```
# Before Prompt
export PROMPT_COMMAND='EXSO=$?;\
    if [[ $EXSO != 0 ]];\
        then\
            ERRMSG="$LRED$EXSO";\
        else\
            ERRMSG="$EXSO";\
    fi;\
PS1="\n$HII[ $LRED\u $SI\W$NM $HII\! / \# / $ERRMSG $HII] $SI$ $IN";'
```

Comment: use `PROMPT_COMMAND` (which is executed before the prompt) to set `PS1` based on the color

Comment: there are many problems here, you should have tested at least *some* parts of it. pleas come up with one specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your assignment to PS1 is only evaluated once, thus exitStatus is only called once. As Nirk also mentions you should use PROMPT_COMMAND. Set it to the command you want executed before every new prompt is displayed. An example:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo -n FAIL:;fi'
```

Will yell FAIL: before every new prompt if the previous command failed:

```
mogul@linuxine:~$ date
Sun Sep 29 21:13:53 CEST 2013
mogul@linuxine:~$ rm crappy_on_existent_file
rm: cannot remove ‘crappy_on_existent_file’: No such file or directory
FAIL:mogul@linuxine:~$
```

Comment: Added what I did based on this to my original post. Thanks champ!